# Can ArcGIS Desktop stack layers?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcgis-desktop, landsat, stack

I have 7 bands of Landsat and I would like to combine all layers into one layer.

Can ArcMap 10 do this like Erdas software can?

Comment: Is this a single, multi-band image?

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the [Composite Bands](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000009p000000) ArcGIS Geoprocessing tool.

According to the ArcGIS Help,

> This tool can also create a raster dataset containing subset of the
>   original raster dataset bands. This is useful if you need to create a
>   new raster dataset with a specific band combination and order.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the following steps if you have ArcGIS 10:

- windows - Image Image Analysis
- Select all layers which you want to stack
- Go to processing tool (Stack).

The files you have selected will be stacked into a one composite layer with colors and bands combination.