# Creating isometric "stack" of raster bands using R?

Tags: raster, r

Is it possible to create an image like this one by using R?

[image]

The image is taken from [UseR! 2019 Spatial workshop part I](https://edzer.github.io/UseR2019/part1.html#c_rastervector_data_cubes,_large_rasters_).

Comment: If the rasters are *exactly* the same size and location you can use Composite Bands https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009p000000 to create a *stacked raster* from a collection of bands. This thread might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67705/can-arcgis-desktop-stack-layers as you say you have access to ArcGIS Pro https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/composite-bands.htm or QGIS https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22300/layer-stacking-rasters-in-qgis

Comment: What have you tried so far?  For questions that involve code (like R) we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.

Comment: The answer is "yes". It is possible to create an image *like* that but how close to that exact image do you want? You can position rasters and view them using the rgl package which gets you 90% of the way there.

Answer (score 3):

using `rgl` and `pals` for colours:

```
> library(rgl)
> library(pals)
```

make some data

```
> m = matrix(runif(54),6,9)
```

cut into 10 categories and lookup colour in a palette of 10 colours:

```
> col = pals::viridis(10)[cut(m, 10)]
```

start the engines...

```
> open3d()
glX 
  5
```

plot as many as you like at different Z coordinates, starting at zero:

```
> surface3d(1:9, 1:6, rep(0,length(col)), color = col, back = "lines", smooth=FALSE)
> surface3d(1:9, 1:6, rep(1,length(col)), color = col, back = "lines", smooth=FALSE)
> surface3d(1:9, 1:6, rep(2,length(col)), color = col, back = "lines", smooth=FALSE)
> surface3d(1:9, 1:6, rep(3,length(col)), color = col, back = "lines", smooth=FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modern solution:
https://www.urbandemographics.org/post/figures-map-layers-r/

Unfortunately it is not a package, but still very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is a CRAN package too: https://marcosci.github.io/layer/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/253432)