# Get all pixel values from superposed rasters

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, mosaic-dataset

I have a set of rasters that overlap pixel by pixel, one of the rasters has more rows and columns than the others, however the position of pixels matches when they're superposed.

I have created a `Mosaic Dataset` which I have loaded with the raster files in question, however when I use the different `Spatial Analysis Tools` in *ArcGIS Pro* like `Summary Statistics` I got a *"Failed to calculated statistics"* message.

How do I generate a raster or an attribute table that contains the pixel values in each of the overlapping rasters? (please see desired output):

| PIXEL_ID | value_raster1 | value_raster2 | value_raster3 | value_raster4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| n | x | y | z | m |

---

as one of my rasters has more cells than the others, I expect to have some null pixel values for certain of the rasters.

Comment: The output you desire is not a raster but a table? So if your largest raster was 10,000 rows by 10,000 columns you want to create a table of 100 million rows?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.
Is it possible to have this result in a raster, in such a way that by clicking on a pixel you can see all the different values of that pixel?

Comment: In a single raster, no. You could explore creating a raster stack or something like a netcdf file format? I've not done that so can't comment on how you create them.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67705/can-arcgis-desktop-stack-layers